# Generate a nested dictionary from a string

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to obtain a nested dictionary from a string, which can be split by delimiter, `:`.

```
s='A:B:C:D'
v=['some','object']
desired={'A':{'B':{'C':{'D':v}}}}
```

Is there a "pythonic" way to generate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a recursive function to do this:

```
>>> s = 'A:B:C:D'
>>> v = ['some','object']
>>> def generate_dict(keys, val):
...     if len(keys) == 1:
...             return {keys[0]: val}
...     return {keys[0]:generate_dict(keys[1:], val)}
...
>>> generate_dict(s.split(':'), v)
{'A': {'B': {'C': {'D': ['some', 'object']}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is iterative solution:

```
result = {}
s = 'A:B:C:D'
delimiter = ":"
value = ['some', 'object']

temp = result
key_list = s.split(delimiter)

for i, key in enumerate(key_list):
    if i != len(key_list) - 1:
        temp[key] = {}
        temp = temp[key]
        continue

    temp[key] = value


print(result)
```